# Swift UserDefaults optional Int

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to set or retrieve value from UserDefaults that is an optional Int, meaning it is either nil or set to a value. I am confused in the setter however. In the code below, I set it to either nil or an integer. I am not sure if this is correct. Is there a better or cleaner way (assuming if at all what I am doing is correct)?

```
public var selectedOption:myOption? {
    get {
        if let opt = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? Int {
            if let val = myOption(rawValue: opt) {
                return val
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    set {
        if let newVal = newValue {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newVal.rawValue, forKey:"myKey")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey:"myKey")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the setter

```
set {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue?.rawValue, forKey:"myKey")
}
```

Due to optional chaining `nil` is written out if `newValue` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public var selectedOption:myOption? {
    get {
        if let opt = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? Int {
            return myOption(rawValue: opt)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue?.rawValue, forKey: "myKey")
    }
}
```

**Or**

Confirm to codable protocol and store the enum instance in UserDefaults

```
enum myOption: Int, Codable {
    case a
    case b
}

public var selectedOption1:myOption? {
    get {
        if let storedObject: Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? Data {
            return try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(myOption.self, from: storedObject)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(newValue), forKey: "myKey")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `set` is fine, but your `get` has a different effect than the `get` in the question, because your `get` cannot return `nil`.

Comment: @robmayoff Enum init will fail if the given int doesnt exist

Comment: That's true, but it's still different than the original `get` if 0 is a valid raw enum value.

Comment: @robmayoff fixed it